# Phantom Content-Security-Policy appears from somewhere

Tags: apache, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm trying to implement a Content-Security-Policy, however the Chrome, Firefox and Edge dev tools all report this as a header (which isn't my policy):

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src https:; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'`

If I generate the header as `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only`, my header *does* appear, but when I change it to `Content-Security-Policy` mine disappears and all I get is the above.

Pretty sure I'm allowed to specify a CSP in local dev.
Is this a default policy that's coming from somewhere? (Apache maybe?)
Even so, why isn't mine overriding it?!